# What is the proper way to schedule a corda flow to execute every X min?

Tags: corda

I need to execute a flow in a node every x min and it is not related to a particular state. For example, every x min I want to bulk cancel all orders that are not valid anymore. How is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the **Heartbeat** sample: https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/heartbeat

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was helpful. How the StartHeartbeatFlow should be initiated in production?

Comment: Anytime Diego, honestly I never used this feature; I'm just aware of the sample project that I shared. Join the Corda slack channel and post a link to your question there: http://slack.corda.net/